# Convert Microsoft word table to html code

Tags: vba, ms-word

need to find every table in ms word and need to html table code through VBA

example

[image]

to

[image]

Comment: need a function that `ActiveDocument.Tables` find and convert to html

Comment: writing to HTML

Comment: @govtexamguru And where exactly do you want to save the HTML code? In a file.html? Or something else ?

Comment: in word file only table replace to HTML code .. there only i can push to database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will generate a variable `Html` with a simple table structure for each table found in your document.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Tables2HTML()
    Dim Tbl As Table
    Dim R As Row
    Dim C As Cell
    Dim T As String
    Dim Html As String
    
    Html = ""
    For Each Tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        Html = Html & "<table>"
        For Each R In Tbl.Rows
            Html = Html & "<tr>"
            For Each C In R.Cells
                T = Replace(C.Range.Text, Chr(7), "")
                Html = Html & "<td>" & T & "</td>"
            Next
            Html = Html & "</tr>"
        Next
        
        Html = Html & "</table>"
    Next
    
    ' Now do what you need with the 'Html' variable. Export it to a file, print it, whatever :)
End Sub
```

I have not added any file saving code, or other outputs. You can simply use `Debug.Print Html` to test the result.